# I saved multiple image views as a single Image inside a layout.But using the same logic I am not able to do it for sharing button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

```
        btnsave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           mainLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
          //  mainLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bitmap =mainLayout.getDrawingCache();


            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File newDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
            newDir.mkdirs();
            Random gen = new Random();
            int n = 10000;
            n = gen.nextInt(n);
            String fotoname = "photo-" + n + ".jpg";
            File file = new File(newDir, fotoname);
            if (file.exists()) file.delete();
            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "saved to your folder", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }     }
    });


    btnshare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            mainLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bitmap =mainLayout.getDrawingCache();//Getting Complication error here.
```

// BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable)ivdisplayphoto.getDrawable();
                // Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
//Using above code I am able to share one imageview.

```
            // Save this bitmap to a file.
            File cache = getApplicationContext().getExternalCacheDir();
            File sharefile = new File(cache, "toshare.png");
            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(sharefile);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }

            // Now send it out to share
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("image/*");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + sharefile));
            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share photo"));
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    });
}
```

I have 3 ImageViews As imageView1,imageView2,imageView3 and  for layout

private RelativeLayout mainLayout;
 mainLayout= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.childLayout);

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap bitmap =mainLayout.getDrawingCache();

Only this was missing.
Now my code is working fine.